# How can any mapping $f:F\to G$ be extended to a group homomorphism uniquely?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In Artin's Algebra, I read the following statement on pg.220:

"Let $F$ be the free group on a set $S=\{a,b,c,\dots\}$, and let $G$ be a group. Every map of sets $f:F\to G$ extends in a unique way to a group homomorphism $\phi:F\to G$. If we denote the image $f(x)$ of an element $x\in S$ by $\overline{x}$, then $\phi$ sends a word in $S'=\{a,a^{-1},b,b^{-1},\dots\}$ to the corresponding product of the elements $\{\overline{a},\overline{a^{-1}},\overline{b},\overline{b^{-1}},\dots\}.$"

How can **any** such $f$ be extended to a homomorphism? Say $f$ is defined thus: $f(a)f(b)\neq f(ab)$. Clearly this $f$ cannot be extended to a homomorphism.

Aso, what does **extends in a unique way** mean here? On face value, it reads like $f$ cannot be extended to a homomorphism in more than one way. But I feel if $f$ is not defined as a homomorphism initially, and extending $f$ to be a homomorphism implies taking a set of generators of $F$ and then defining $f$ for words formed form these generators accordingly, then $f$ does **not** extend to a homomorphism uniquely.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean $S\to G$ extends. Why do you feel that $f$'s values on the generators of $F$ do not uniquely determine $f$'s values on all of $F$?

Answer (score 3):

It *should* read that any map of sets $f:S\to G$ uniquely extends to a homomorphism $\phi:F\to G$. A homomorphism is uniquely determined by its actions on a set of generators--which is precisely determined by $f:S\to G$ in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is incorrect - clearly not every function $F\to G$ is a homomorphism. What *is* true is that any map $S \to G$ extends uniquely to a homomorphism $F \to G$ - for any string $cab\ldots$ in $F$, we must have $f(ca^{-1}b\ldots) = f(c)f(a)^{-1}f(b)\ldots$, so the homomorphism is determined by its values on $S$.

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake: it must be "every map $f:S\to G$ extends..." Then the expression $f(a)f(b)\neq f(ab)$ is meanless, since $f(ab)$ is not given.

Comment: Note that $ab$ is not a member of $S$...

Comment: @Kris; Yes, of course.

Comment: the comment was more for the question-asker's benefit :)

Comment: @Kris: Dear Kris, I repeat: Yes, of course. :-)